# Dynamically render iframes from list of html files in folder

Tags: iframe

I have a list of html files in /apps folder and a menu.html file which presents list of apps (right now it is an hardcoded list of apps). What I would like to do is to dynamically load all html files in the apps folder. first.html, second.html, third.html, etc... and present those web pages from within iframes so that the user can connect with each one of those apps through the menu.html website
so that in menu.html there will be links for:

```
<iframe src='app1.html' ...>
<iframe src='app2.html' ...>
```

and whenever the user adds an application to that folder, menu.html will load this new app as well.

I read that in Javascript there is no access to file system, so I assume the way to eat that task is using nodeJS file module.

My project folder looks like that:

```
menu.html
menu.js
menu.css
/apps
/apps/first.html
/apps/second.html
/apps/third.html
etc . .
```

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did was simply using nodejs to add a new endpoint - this endpoint would return a list of urls to iframes of apps. The list is generated by a simple 'walk', recursive search for files (index.html of each app) on the /apps  folder, than in the client a fetch from this end point and then simply iterate on the response which is an array of links to local iframes and the render iframe tags with the src value equsl the current array value in the loop